# How to delete top and last non empty lines of the file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to delete top and last non empty line of the file.

Example:

```
cat test.txt

//blank_line
abc
def
xyz
//blank_line
qwe
mnp
//blank_line
```

Then output should be:

```
def
xyz
//blank_line
qwe
```

I have tried with commands

```
sed "$(awk '/./{line=NR} END{print line}' test.txt)d" test.txt
```

to remove last non empty line. At here there are two command, (1) sed and (2) awk. But I want to do by single command.

Comment: But `//blank_line`s in the middle of the text should stay, right?

Comment: Please post your efforts in your post, which you have put to solve this problem.

Comment: Too bad the question was badly formed, I was looking forward to seeing solutions to this one. OP, fix that question ASAP and let's get this reopened.

Comment: Hi James,     Blank line in the middle of the test should be stay. Just remove first and last non empty line.

Comment: Hi Ravinder,   I have tried with commands - sed "$(awk '/./{line=NR} END{print line}' test.txt)d" test.txt  to remove last non empty line. At here there are two command, (1) sed and (2) awk. But I want to do by single command. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a double pass method:

```
 awk '(NR==FNR) { if(NF) {t=FNR;if(!h) h=FNR}; next}
      (h<FNR && FNR<t)' file file
```

The integers `h` and `t` keep track of the head and the tail. In this case, empty lines can also contain blanks. You could replace `if(NF)` by `if(length($0)==0)` to be more strict.

This one reads everything into memory and does a simple replace at the end:

```
$ awk '{b=b RS $0}
       END{ sub(/^[[:blank:]\n]*[^\n]+\n/,"",b);
            sub(/\n[^\n]+[[:blank:]\n]*$,"",b);
            print b }' file
```

Comment: I think your first solution is the best approach, compared to keeping the file in memory double scan is better.  For small files both will work fine, but this can scale for larger files.  The inner if should be `if(!h)`, also in the first block you can use `NR` instead of `FNR`.  Additionally with `file{,}`  you'll type the filename just once.

Comment: @karakfa Thanks for the fix. I do not want to use `NR` as I believe that `FNR` is a better choice for doing multi passes. Mixing NR and FNR is just confusing. FNR stands for file number of records and makes more sense here.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the whole file in memory at once with GNU sed for -E and -z:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/^\s*\S+\n//; s/\n\s*\S+\s*$/\n/' test.txt
def
xyz

qwe
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{gsub(/^\s*\S+\n|\n\S+\s*$/,"")} 1' test.txt
def
xyz

qwe
```

Both GNU tools accept \s and \S as shorthand for [[:space:]] and [^[:space:]] respectively and GNU sed accepts the non-POSIX-sed-standard \n as meaning newline.

Answer (score 2):

A single-pass, fast and relatively memory-efficient approach utilising a buffer:

```
awk 'f {
    if(NF) {
        printf "%s",buf
        buf=""
    }
    buf=(buf $0 ORS)
    next
}
NF {
    f=1
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a golfed version of @kvantour's solution

```
$ awk 'NR==(n=FNR){e=!NF?e:n;b=!b?e:b}b<n&&n<e' file{,}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '0,/\S/d;H;$!d;x;s/.(.*)\n.*\S.*/\1/' file
```

Use a range to delete upto and including the first line containing a non-space character. Then copy the remains of the file into the hold space and at the end of file use substitution to remove the last line containing a non-space character and any empty lines to the end of the file.

Alternative:

```
sed '0,/\S/d' file | tac | sed '0,/\S/d'| tac
```